# Convert SQL Condition to Pyspark

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, where-clause

How to implement this query in Pyspark?

I need to convert this clause where I use exist into another dataframe.

```
SELECT 
  c.Id, c.Description, c.Code
FROM charlie as c                                                                              
Where (
            c.Status = 'ACTIVE' or
            exists (
                select 1 from beta as b                                                     
                    where c.Id = b.Id
            )
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, exists

charlie_df.select("Id", "Description", "Code") \
.where((col("Status") == "ACTIVE") |
exists(charlie_df.select("*").join("beta", charlie_df.Id == "beta.Id")))
```